# ADD a new column into an XTS object

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Hi: I have an xts object as such:

```
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2013-09-09    505.00    507.92   503.48     506.17    12116200        506.17
2013-09-10    506.20    507.45   489.50     494.64    26490200        494.64
2013-09-11    467.01    473.69   464.81     467.71    32031600        467.71
2013-09-12    468.50    475.40   466.01     472.69    14409400        472.69
```

I try to calculate a rolling mean and attach it to a new column as such

```
AA["AAPL.Rolling"] <- rollmean(AA[,"AAPL.Adjusted"],12)
```

Although the `rollmean(AA[,"AAPL.Adjusted"],12)` works on its own; I get an error message when I try to attach to a new column. 
** also what makes this hard is that the new rolling mean will not have data in every row since the first 12 should be "NA" Can anyone help?  Thank you much.

Comment: Your attempted solution doesn't make any sense. `rnorm(12, AA)` gives you 12 observations from a random normal distribution with `mean=AA[1:12,1]` and sd=1. That's not even close to a rolling mean. And you're trying to add a zoo object as a column of an xts object? Why do you think that should work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't add columns to zoo/xts objects like that.  You can use the `$<-` function though.

```
AA$AAPL.Rolling <- rollmean(AA[,"AAPL.Adjusted"], 12)
```

Also note that `rollmean` is center-aligned by default.  You may want to use `rollmeanr` to get right-alignment.  Padding with `NA` will happen automatically, since you're merging the rolling mean with the original object.  Use `fill=NA` if you want `rollmean` to add them explicitly.

Comment: This is perfect; even anticipated a problem with rollmean!

Comment: interested to know Josh's opinion on adding a character vector to these xts objects.  so you'd have one char column and one int/numeric column....

Comment: @d8aninja: That's not possible because xts objects are based on the matrix class, and you can't have columns with different types in a matrix.  That said, there has been some experimentation with an "xtsdf" class.

Comment: I see. Trying to think about making these objects ggplot and highcharter friendly. The latter especially has some nice presets for xts ("stock" type) but if you want to dynamically lab the series you've got to switch over to a data.frame and use zoo::index to pull off the xts rownames into a column